# Waveform jitter occurs after a certain time

Tags: lightningchart

**My expectation** is that the waveform to remain stable for a long time without jitter when the project runs for a long time.

**My problem** is that after running my project for about 20 minutes, a waveform jitter appears, as shown below.

[Run for a few minutes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCQAz.png)

[Run for about twenty minutes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FzqV.png)

But only sine waves seem to wobble, not [straight lines and square waves.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hMZM.png)

Another problem that happens at the same time is that the X-axis doesn't scale properly, and at a certain range you can't zoom in anymore, and you can see that the X-axis starts and ends quite a long way off. And I'm not putting any restrictions on the interaction properties.

**My environment**: Chrome(version 113.0.5672.127), windows 10, lcjs(4.2.0), node(14.21.3)

**I tried** different frequencies(dataPointsPerSecond). I found that the jitter appeared later at lower frequencies.

After the waveform wobbled, I tried to store the X-axis coordinates of the current data and reset it to start at 0. Then the waveform returns to normal, and so does the X-axis scale. But when I restored the stored X-axis, the problem reappeared.

I tried different "AxisTickStrategies" like "Numeric" and "Time".

I also tried these properties:

```
.ChartXY({
  container: `${this.chartId}`,
  theme: this.$myTheme,
  antialias: true,
  lineAntiAlias: true,
  webgl: {
    version: "webgl2"
  }
})
```

**The code** I use in [this example](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0028-multiChannelLineProgressiveOwnAxes.html?disable-animations=1&isList=false) is as follows.

```
const lcjs = require('@arction/lcjs');
const DATA_FREQUENCY_HZ = 10000
const {
    lightningChart,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    AxisScrollStrategies,
    synchronizeAxisIntervals,
    UIOrigins,
    UIDraggingModes,
    SolidFill,
    ColorRGBA,
    SolidLine,
    Themes
} = lcjs;
const axisStyleHighlight = new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(255, 255, 255, 0) });

const chart = lightningChart()
    .ChartXY({
        theme: Themes.light
    })
    .setPadding({ left: 0, right: 90, top: 20, bottom: 0 })
    .setTitle('')
    .setBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(255, 255, 255) }));

const axisX = chart
    .getDefaultAxisX()
    .setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    .setOverlayStyle(axisStyleHighlight)
    .setNibOverlayStyle(axisStyleHighlight)
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)
    .setTitle('Time')
    .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Time)
    .setInterval({ start: 0, end: 2000, animate: false, stopAxisAfter: false }); // 0, this.xIntervalDefault

const axisY = chart
    .getDefaultAxisY()
    .setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    .setOverlayStyle(axisStyleHighlight)
    .setNibOverlayStyle(axisStyleHighlight)
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)
    .setTitle('Amplitude')
    .setInterval({ start: -1, end: 1, animate: false, stopAxisAfter: false });

const series = chart
    .addLineSeries({
        dataPattern: { pattern: 'ProgressiveX' },
        automaticColorIndex: 0
    })
    .setName(`Channel 1`)
    .setDataCleaning({ minDataPointCount: 10000 })
    .setStrokeStyle(style => style.setThickness(2));

// Add legend
const legend = chart
    .addLegendBox()
    .add(chart)
    .setDraggingMode(UIDraggingModes.notDraggable)
    .setPosition({ x: 100, y: 100 })
    .setOrigin(UIOrigins.RightTop)
    .setMargin({ right: 5, top: 20.3 })
    .setPadding({ left: 3, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 })
    .setEntries((entry, component) =>
        entry
            .setButtonOnStrokeStyle(
                new SolidLine({
                    thickness: 1,
                    fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(0, 0, 0) })
                })
            )
            .setTextFont(font => font.setSize(11))
    )
    .setTitle('');

// Generate data sets that are repeated for each channel for demonstration purposes.
const dataSets = [
    { length: Math.ceil(400 * Math.PI), func: (x) => 8 * Math.sin(x / 100) },  // sine wave
    // { length: Math.ceil(400 * Math.PI), func: (x) => 1 }, // Straight line
    // { length: Math.ceil(400 * Math.PI), func: (x) =>  Math.sign(Math.sin(x/10)) }, // Square wave
].map((config) => {
    const data = []
    data.length = config.length
    for (let i = 0; i < config.length; i += 1) {
        const y = config.func(i)
        data[i] = y
    }
    return data
})
const dataSet = dataSets[0]

// Stream data into series.
let tStart = window.performance.now();
let pushedDataCount = 0;
let step = 0.1
const streamData = () => {
    const tNow = window.performance.now();
    const shouldBeDataPointsCount = Math.floor((DATA_FREQUENCY_HZ * (tNow - tStart)) / 1000);
    const newDataPointsCount = Math.min(shouldBeDataPointsCount - pushedDataCount, DATA_FREQUENCY_HZ); // Add max 1000 data points per frame into a series. This prevents massive performance spikes when switching tabs for long times

    const newDataPoints = [];
    for (let iDp = 0; iDp < newDataPointsCount; iDp++) {
        const x = (pushedDataCount + iDp) * step;
        const iData = (pushedDataCount + iDp) % dataSet.length;
        const y = dataSet[iData];
        const point = { x, y };
        newDataPoints.push(point);
    }
    // console.log(newDataPoints);
    series.add(newDataPoints)
    pushedDataCount += newDataPointsCount;
    requestAnimationFrame(streamData);
};
streamData();
```

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me why this problem is happening and how to fix it. Thank you all!

Comment: Well, It seems that the following property solved this problem.
`defaultAxisX: {type: 'linear-highPrecision'}` in `AxisOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It seems that the following property when creating ChartXY solved this problem. `defaultAxisX: {type: 'linear-highPrecision'}` in **AxisOptions**.